# Select an element where one of its classes starts with a certain string

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following jQuery code:

```
$("body.page-calendar-practices-2012-05 #content-header h1#title")
```

which works fine. I can use it to alter the html in my page. But I really want to select pages which have a class in the body STARTING WITH 'page-calendar-practices' ie: it will include other pages with different dates. I tried the following:

```
$("body[class^=page-calendar-practices] #content-header h1#title")
```

and it didn't work. What is wrong?

**EDIT** - here's the HTML:

```
<body class="not-front logged-in page-calendar two-sidebars page-calendar-practices-2012-05 section-calendar" >
```

Comment: Are you sure the class starts with that?  The syntax of your first selector is incorrect (note `]`)

Comment: It works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rekqG/

Comment: save everyone from guessing and post enough live html to see what you are actually traversing

Comment: Sorry about the syntax, I copy pasted it wrong. But yest, the class starts with that, I am looking at it right now.

Comment: also quote attribute values in selectors per examples in API http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[class^=page-calendar-practices]` will only select an element who's class attribute starts with "page-calendar-practices"; not an element of which *one of its classes* starts with "page-calendar-practices".

So it *would* select an element such as this:

```
<body class="page-calendar-practices-2012-05">
```

---

You can use the `*` selector:

```
$('body[class*=page-calendar-practices]')
```

but that will also select the following:

```
<body class="page some-page-calendar-practices">
```

---

Alternatively, you can filter with this simple check:

```
$('body').filter(function() {
    return ~(' ' + this.className).indexOf(' page-calendar-practices');
}).find('#content-header h1#title');
```

which is a little more verbose than the simple "contains" selector, but is more accurate.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DR9K4/

---

To make things easier, you can add your own filter to jQuery, as follows:

```
jQuery.expr[':']['class-starts']​ = function(el, i, m) {
    return ~(' ' + el.className).indexOf(' ' + m[3]);
};
```

and then simply use it wherever you want:

```
$('body:class-starts(page-calendar-practices)');
```

See it here in action: http://jsfiddle.net/gEJeW/

---

**Update:** In jQuery 1.8, [the Sizzle engine was completely rewritten](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/07/04/the-new-sizzle/). As part of the update, the expression extension architecture has also been reworked, so the above function won't work anymore.

If you're using jQuery 1.8+, use this:

```
$.expr[':']['class-starts'] = $.expr.createPseudo(function (arg) {
    return function (el) {
        return ~(' ' + el.className).indexOf(' ' + arg);
    };
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gEJeW/2/

---

For more information, see here: [Getting the "match" object in a Custom Filter Selector in jQuery 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624345/getting-the-match-object-in-a-custom-filter-selector-in-jquery-1-8)

Comment: Ok, so how can I write a selector which will make the selection that I want.

Comment: +1 Nice jQuery custom selector.  I didn't know it was that easy to do.

Comment: @jfriend00 - Unfortunately, it's not that easy anymore. See my update.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt is looking for a class attribute that starts with your string, not a specific class name in that attribute that starts with your string.

I think you can probably just use the attribute contains logic:

```
$("body[class*='page-calendar-practices'] #content-header h1#title")
```

This could match class names that don't start with that, but it seems unlikely you'd be using class names like that.

---

If you wanted to be exact, I don't think you could do it in a simple selector - you'd probably need some javascript logic:

```
$(document.body).filter(function() {
    return((" " + this.className).indexOf(" page-calendar-practices") != -1);
}).find("#content-header h1#title");
```

Comment: +1 I like the way you prepend a space, then just use that in your regex. Nice touch!

Comment: @JosephSilber - I just removed the regex since I realized it wasn't needed.  I learned the space addition trick in jQuery source.  I like your jQuery custom selector.  I didn't know it was that easy to extend.

Comment: That's right. Hope you don't mind me *borrowing* this method for my filter expression.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

`jQuery('[attribute^="value"]')`

**Description: Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.**

Yours doesn't start with it - it has the matching string halfway through

You want to use the `*` selector: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/