# Getting the "match" object in a Custom Filter Selector in jQuery 1.8

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

For reference, here's an article on [**Creating a Custom Filter Selector with jQuery**](http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/1055-creating-a-custom-filter-selector-with-jquery/).

---

#### Introduction:

For those not familiar with **jQuery's Custom Filter Selectors**, here's a quick primer on what they are:

If you need a reusable [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/), you can extend jQuery’s selector expressions by adding your own functions to the `jQuery.expr[':']` object.

The function will be run on each element in the current collection and should return true or false (much like [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)). Three bits of information are passed to this function:

1. The element in question
2. The index of this element among the entire collection
3. A `match` array returned from a regular expression match that contains important information for the more complex expressions.

Once you've extended `jQuery.expr[':']`, you can use it as a filter in your jQuery selector, much like you would use any of the built-in ones (`:first`, `:last`, `:eq()` etc.)

---

Here's an example where we'll filter for elements that have more than one class assigned to them:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].hasMultipleClasses = function(elem, index, match) {
    return elem.className.split(' ').length > 1;
};

$('div:hasMultipleClasses');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acTeJ/

---

In the example above, we have not used the `match` array being passed in to our function. Let's try a more complex example. Here we'll create a filter to match elements that have a higher `tabindex` than the number specified:

```
jQuery.expr[':'].tabindexAbove = function(elem, index, match) {
    return +elem.getAttribute('tabindex') > match[3];
};

$('input:tabindexAbove(4)');
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YCsCm/

The reason this works is because the `match` array is the actual array returned from the regex that was used to parse the selector. So in our example, [`match` would be the following array](http://jsfiddle.net/YCsCm/1/):

```
[":tabIndexAbove(4)", "tabIndexAbove", "", "4"]
```

As you can see, we can get to the value inside the parentheses by using `match[3]`.

---

#### The Question:

In jQuery 1.8, [the `match` array is no longer being passed in to the filter function](http://jsfiddle.net/YCsCm/2/). Since we have no access to the info being passed in, [the `tabindexAbove` filter does not work anymore](http://jsfiddle.net/YCsCm/3/) (the only difference between this fiddle and the one above, is that this uses a later version of jQuery).

So, here are several points I'd like clarified:

1. Is this expected behavior? Is it documented anywhere?
2. Does this have anything to do with the fact that [`Sizzle` has been updated](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/07/04/the-new-sizzle/) (even though it clearly states that "the old API for Sizzle was not changed in this rewrite". Maybe this is what they mean by "the removal of the now unnecessary `Sizzle.filter`")?
3. Now that we have no access to the `match` array, is there any other way to get to the info being passed in to the filter (in our case, `4`)?

[I never found any documentation in the jQuery Docs about the custom filter selectors](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adocs.jquery.com+custom+filter+selector), so I don't know where to start looking for information about this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

jQuery has added a utility for creating custom pseudos in Sizzle. It's a little more verbose, but it's much more readable than using match[3]. It also has the advantage of being more performant as you can avoid repeating tedious calculations every time an element is tested. The answer that has already been accepted is a good answer, but let me add a note to say that you can use $.expr.createPseudo instead of setting the sizzleFilter property yourself, which will save a little space.

```
jQuery.expr[':'].tabIndexAbove = $.expr.createPseudo(function( tabindex ) {
    return function(elem) {
        return +elem.getAttribute('tabindex') > tabindex;
    }
});

$('input:tabIndexAbove(4)').css('background', 'teal');
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/timmywil/YCsCm/7/

This is all documented on Sizzle's github:
https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation

Comment: +1 for the link to the docs. Accepted for the `createPseudo` factory.

Answer (score 7):

By looking at the jQuery 1.8 beta2 source and the "Extensibility" section of [*The New Sizzle*](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/07/04/the-new-sizzle/), you have to set `fn.sizzleFilter` to `true` in order to get the pseudo argument and the context. If not, you'll just get all the elements in the arguments.

Here is the code that does the same thing as your example. Use the `selector` parameter passed in the function to get the pseudo argument.

Here is the [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/YCsCm/6/) on jsfiddle.

As mentioned in the blog post above, you can even pre-compile and cache the your selector.

```js
var sizzle = jQuery.find;

var tabIndexAbove = function( selector, context, isXml ) {
    return function( elem ) {
        return elem.getAttribute("tabindex") > selector;
    };
};

/*
 fn.sizzleFilter is set to true to indicate that tabIndexAbove 
 is a function that will return a function for use by the compiler 
 and should be passed the pseudo argument, the context, and 
 whether or not the current context is xml. If this property is 
 not set, adding pseudos works similar to past versions of Sizzle
*/
tabIndexAbove.sizzleFilter = true;
sizzle.selectors.pseudos.tabIndexAbove = tabIndexAbove;

$('input:tabIndexAbove(4)').css('background', 'teal');
```

Just a note, if you're looking at the source, jQuery slightly changed the structure that the public-facing interface points to.

In jQuery 1.7.2:

```
jQuery.find = Sizzle;
jQuery.expr = Sizzle.selectors;
jQuery.expr[":"] = jQuery.expr.filters;
```

In jQuery 1.8b2:

```
jQuery.find = Sizzle;
jQuery.expr = Sizzle.selectors;
jQuery.expr[":"] = jQuery.expr.pseudos;
```

Comment: +1 Great answer! Thanks. It's just a pity that the new way of doing it is so much more verbose. (BTW, [you can see all the Sizzle aliases here](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/sizzle-jquery.js)). For some reason I still don't fully grok the method they're using to compile the selector functions. Do you know of any source that explains this in more detail?

Comment: Thanks. I did a quick search but unfortunately I didn't find anything specifically useful besides the blog post and the source code. Let me try to find one; otherwise we might need to dig into the source.

Comment: Was afraid that's the case. I was rummaging through the source code, but still didn't get the full picture; I think I'll have to dedicate a little more time to fully comprehend all this. Thanks again for a great answer!