# How to fix the jQuery 1.8 “unsupported pseudo” error?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, sizzle, gruntjs

A plugin I’m using relies on `$(':animated')`, but since I upgraded to jQuery 1.8.0 this throws an error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: animated

Did jQuery 1.8.0 drop support for this custom selector as part of its changes in Sizzle? How do I fix this?

Comment: Ah, I see jQuery 1.8 has just been released. I'm curious, does it canonicalize the term "pseudo-selector"? I sure hope not, although looking at the error message and the fact that [`$.expr.filters` is now `$.expr.pseudos`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624345/getting-the-match-object-in-a-custom-filter-selector-in-jquery-1-8), that seems to be the case...

Answer (score 3):

Don’t worry, jQuery 1.8.0 still supports [the custom `$(':animated')` selector](http://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/).

However, contrary to what you might expect, it’s not part of Sizzle (jQuery’s selector engine). If you’re using a custom build, make sure you don’t exclude the `effects` module, which [defines the `:animated` selector](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/95559f5117c8a21c1b8cc99f4badc320fd3dcbda/src/effects.js#L647-653).

For example, if you were creating a custom jQuery build using this command before:

```
grunt custom:-ajax,-deprecated,-effects
```

You’ll need to remove the `-effects` part, like this:

```
grunt custom:-ajax,-deprecated
```

Else the `:animated` selector won’t be supported.

Comment: `Don’t worry` I wasn't... Oops, just noticed you were talking to yourself and not me ;)

Comment: From the blog entry:  **Modularity:** *If you know your project’s jQuery dependencies well,*  I assume the plugin is animating things so it is checking :animated? Or does it not do animations and need that for some other purpose?

Comment: @DaveMethvin Here’s the plugin: https://github.com/Wilto/Dynamic-Carousel/blob/master/plugin.js It uses `jQuery#animate` only if CSS transitions aren’t supported, but it does use the `:animated` selector in either case.