# Opposite of jQuery's :eq()

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Does anyone know if there exist some kind of selector to select al the elements from a matched set but the one given by the indicated index. E.g.:

```
$("li").neq(2).size();
```

Supposing that there were 5 elements, the last statement would give you 4, and would contain all the `<li>` elements but the second one in the DOM.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Use [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$('li').not(':eq(2)');
```

Comment: if you want the fastest neq use a filter see http://jsperf.com/jquery-fastest-neq-filter

Answer (score 10):

Alright, it's just

```
$("li:not(:eq(2))");
```

Answer (score 7):

The other answers will work just fine, but as an alternative you could implement you own custom selector for `neq`

```
$.extend($.expr[":"], {  
    neq: function(elem, i, match) {  
        return i !== (match[3] - 0);
    }  
});
```

And then you could do what you originally suggested.

```
$("li:neq(2)").size();
```

Although another post suggested using `.length` instead of `.size`, which will be better as its just a property and not an extra function call.

```
$("li:neq(2)").length;
```

Comment: Watch the syntax, it has changed in 1.8 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624345/getting-the-match-object-in-a-custom-filter-selector-in-jquery-1-8

Comment: Also, doesn't this create a pseudo selector, not a method? `$("li:neq(2)")`

Answer (score 6):

I would use filter for such case,

```
$('li').filter(function (i, item) {
   return i != 2;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the custom selector, you could also implement this as a jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.neg = function (index) {
    return this.pushStack( this.not(':eq(' + index + ')') );
}
```