# How to animate the caption for each slide individually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have made a custom jquery slideshow which is working as required. The only thing remaining is animating the caption inside the slide. I want the caption to respond to the current slide but the problem is all of the captions respond no matter which slide is showing. I cannot seem to fix this issue.

```
<body>
    <div class="marquee_container">
        <div class="holder">
            <div class="slide">
                <img class="marquee_panel_photo" src="images/photos/london.jpg" alt="London" />
                <div class="marquee_caption">
                    <div class="marquee_caption_content">
                        <p>Content goes here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
                <img class="marquee_panel_photo" src="images/photos/milan.jpg" alt="milan" />
                <div class="marquee_caption">
                    <div class="marquee_caption_content">
                        <p>Content goes here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slide">
               <img class="marquee_panel_photo" src="images/photos/staugustine.jpg" alt="staugustine" />
                <div class="marquee_caption">
                    <div class="marquee_caption_content">
                        <p>Content goes here</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="marquee_nav">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.marquee_container { 
    width: 700px; 
    height: 350px; 
    overflow: hidden; 
    margin: 0px 0px 30px 0px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    position:relative;
}
.holder{
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    width: 9999px; 
    height: 350px; 
}
.slide{
    width: 700px;
    float: left;
    position:relative;
}
.marquee_photos { 
    overflow:hidden;
}
.marquee_photos img{
    display:block;
}
.marquee_caption {
    width: 700px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 15px 0px 10px 0px;
    color: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 0px;
    background: url(images/template/marquee_caption.png) 0px 0px;
}
.marquee_caption_content { 
    width: 410px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 25px;
}
.marquee_nav{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:5px;
    right:0;    
}
.marquee_nav .marquee_nav_item{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    background:url(images/template/nav_buttons.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    overflow:hidden;
    display:block;
    width:17px;
    height:18px;
    float:left;
    margin:0 4px;
}
.marquee_nav .marquee_nav_item:hover{
    background:url(images/template/nav_buttons.png) no-repeat -25px 0;
}
.marquee_nav .marquee_nav_item.selected{
    background:url(images/template/nav_buttons.png) no-repeat -50px 0;
}
```

JQUERY

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    //1st STEP
    //generating nav links automatically
    //for each slide there should be a nav item
    $('.slide').each(function(index, value){

        $('.marquee_nav').append('<a href="#" class="marquee_nav_item"></a>');

    });

    //2nd STEP
    //setting the nav links and running the slide
    $('.marquee_nav .marquee_nav_item').on('click', function(){

        $('.marquee_nav_item').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');

        //3rd STEP
        //animating the slideshow
        //getting the index value of the clicked nav
        var navClick = $(this).index();

        /* holder width set to the parent width because the holder width is 9999px and we will use that to change
           the margin-left position of the images */
        var holderWidth = $('.marquee_container').width();

        /* position of the new img according to the nav item clicked. If the 3 nav item is clicked jquery will get that
           index value and will multiply it with the holder width to know how much distance it has to move for eg.
           if the 2nd nav is clicked, the index is 1, so 1 * with the holderWidth which is 700 = 700. So it will move margin-left
            -700px. See the animate function below */
        var photoPosition = navClick * holderWidth;
        //alert(photoPosition);

        //slideshow animation
        $('.marquee_container .holder').animate({'margin-left' : -photoPosition}, 1000);

        //animating the caption
        $('.marquee_caption').animate({'top':275}, 500);

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you need to first send all the `.marquee_caption` elements back to their original position and then bring only the selected one into the view.

Something like:

```
...
$('.marquee_caption').not(':eq(' + navClick + ')').animate({ 'top': 200 }, 500);
$('.marquee_caption').eq(navClick).animate({ 'top': 100 }, 500);
...
```

where `navClick` is the variable you already have in your code which stores `.index()` of the selected navigation element. And `.eq()` is the jQuery method you pass this `navClick` value into.

Here is a modified **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nmn1j77q/1/)** as an example using your own code for simplicity sake.

Hope this is what you were looking for.

***Update:***

- The **[`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** method of jQuery takes an `index` parameter to retrieve only *one* element out of a set of elements.
- The **[`.not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not/)** method selects everything *except* the selector rule passed to it.
- So in the first line above, out of the **3** `.marquee_caption` elements, we are selecting *all* elements *except* the currently selected one as per the `navClick` *index*. So the resulting jQuery object contains **2 out of 3** elements. And then we `.animate()` them as usual.
- Finally, you can simply trigger the `click` event on the respective `.marquee_nav_item` element by utilising the same `.eq()` method i.e. just before your `$(document).ready(...)` function closes, add this: `$('.marquee_nav .marquee_nav_item').eq(0).trigger('click');`.
- This is one of the options by the way, and probably the quickest and dirtiest. What is happening is that you are *triggering* the click event manually and hence everything, defined in the `click` function above, follows.

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you so much. Can you explain this code in a little bit more detail or provide any helpful link. One more thing. How can I show the first slide active on page load? Right now neither the caption is active nor is the nav item selected

Comment: added an **Update** above. hope it helps. Also read **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12057251/opposite-of-jquerys-eq)**.

Answer (score 0):

```
//animation the caption
$(this).parents('.slide').find('.marquee_caption').animate({'top':275}, 500);
```

Is this what you mean?

Comment: No, I want the current slide caption to animate but the problem is that all the captions are animating at the same time.