# Remove all element without attribute

Tags: javascript, html

I try to understand how to remove all children elements without specified attribute for example:

**This is the html:**

```
<div class="container">
  <span></span>
  <div></div>
  <strong data-*></strong>
  <p></p>
  <div data-*></div>
</div>
```

What i want is to remove all element inside the container and without **data-*** attribute.

**data-***

The attribute can be **data-anything** (data-color, data-border, etc).

I'm looking **javascript only solution**.

Comment: If you're using jQuery, now would be the time to speak up ?

Comment: Can you show your real HTML?

Comment: I'm not using jQuery for this project.

Comment: If you were using jQuery, this would have been the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199008/find-html-based-on-partial-attribute Just posting it in case someone finds it in a search.

Comment: It's possible, but it would be extremely slow. (Check all elements on page, load attributes into an array, search the array for `data-`, and finally remove the element if there's no match)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `.filter()`, `.some()` and `.forEach()` should do the trick.

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".container *");

[].filter.call(els, function(el) {
    return ![].some.call(el.attributes, function(attr) {
        return /^data/i.test(attr.name);
    });
}).forEach(function(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
});
```

---

You'll need patches for old browsers, but you probably knew that already.

---

If like me, you like reusable functions:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".container *");

[].filter.call(els, els_with_no_data)
  .forEach(remove_nodes);
```

---

```
function remove_nodes(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}

function has_data_attrs(attr) {
    return /^data/i.test(attr.name);
}

function els_with_no_data(el) {
    return ![].some.call(el.attributes, has_data_attrs)
}
```

---

And then using *Array generics* (in supported browsers, otherwise polyfiilled):

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".container *");

Array.filter(els, els_with_no_data)
     .forEach(remove_nodes);
```

---

```
function remove_nodes(el) {
    el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
}

function has_data_attrs(attr) {
    return /^data/i.test(attr.name);
}

function els_with_no_data(el) {
    return !Array.some(el.attributes, has_data_attrs)
}
```

Comment: `>_<` That's exactly what I wanted to write.

Comment: Gotcha! You need to reverse the collection. Otherwise you may have `null` accessing `el.parentNode`, since `qSA` place parents first.

Comment: @kirilloid: Hmmm... I don't understand. Even if the parent is removed first, there shouldn't be anything preventing the child from being removed as well (though it would be unnecessary). Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe, I overthought it.

Comment: @kirilloid: Still, it could be a worthwhile optimization to have nodes check to see if they still descend from the `.container` before checking their attributes and removing them. Once their ancestor is removed, there's not much point in removing it.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong. Detached DOM nodes do not become `null`s automatically for their children.
For the sake of optimization reordering may be interesting. Actually you'll need to walk nodes "by yourself" then.

Comment: Well, someone didn't like this answer. Not enough jQuery? Or did I miss something in my implementation?

Comment: @kirilloid: If we had an outer loop, or if there was only one `container`, we could do `if (container.compareDocumentPosition(el) & 16) {`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49181/discussion-between-kirilloid-and-cookie-monster)

Comment: @cookiemonster Thank you i think your solution is the most descriptive and flexible.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it

```
var parent = document.querySelector('.container');
var elems  = parent.querySelectorAll('*');

for (var i=elems.length; i--;) {
    var attr    = elems[i].attributes,
        hasData = false;

    for (var j = attr.length; j--;) {
        if ( attr[j].name.indexOf('data') === 0 ) {
            hasData = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if ( ! hasData ) parent.removeChild(elems[i]);
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Zb4bE/2/)

`querySelector(All)` will have to be polyfilled if you need to support IE7 and below.

Answer (score 2):

There is probbaly better ways, just had a few minutes to waste so thought I would play with the answer.

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
var children = container.childNodes;

for (var i=children.length-1;i--) {

    var child = children[i];    
    if (child.nodeType===1) {  //make sure it is an element, not a text node
        var hasMatch = false;
        var attrs = child.attributes;  //get the attributes of the element
        for(var j=0; j<attrs.length;j++){  //loop through
            if(attrs[j].nodeName.indexOf("data-")===0) {  //if it starts we have a match
               hasMatch = true;
               break;
            }
        }
        if (!hasMatch) {
            container.removeChild(child);  //if no match, remove it
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 I'll upvote that, it's basically the same I came up with, and not all the overly clever stupidness of the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

Reworked solution of `@cookie monster`:

```
(function r (nodelist) {
    // reduceRight is used only to walk in reverse direction
    [].reduceRight.call(nodelist, function (dummy, e) {
        if ([].every.call(e.attributes, function(a) {
            return !/^data/i.test(a.name);
        })) return e.parentNode.removeChild(e);
        r(e.children);
    }, "filler");
}(document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].children));
```

Comment: ...except I don't think you want `.every()`. That'll only be true if every attribute for the current element is a `data` attribute.

Comment: ...nevermind, you're right. I had it turned around. Didn't see thenegation on the regexp.

Comment: Can you please post a FIDDLE

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var objects = document.querySelectorAll('.container *');
var parent = document.getElementsByClassName('container')[0];

for (var i = objects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (objects[i].attributes[0]) {
        if (objects[i].attributes[0].name.indexOf('data-') == -1) {
            parent.removeChild(objects[i]);
        }
    } else {
        parent.removeChild(objects[i]);
    }
}
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5x4xN/1/)</kbd>