# JavaScript/CSS selector for attribute name pattern

Tags: javascript, css, css-selectors

Assuming I have the following markup

```
<div data-common-notcommon="anyValue">
    <!-- Whatever.. -->
</div>

<div data-common-not-commonerthing="anyValue">
    <!-- Whatever.. -->
</div>
```

I'm trying to write a JS selector (or a CSS selector, don't care for the difference..) to find attributes based on a common, partial attribute name.

I.E I want to find all the elements that start with `data-common`.

I can't find anything on Google for attribute name selectors but rather attribute value selectors which I don't really want to do.

```
<script>
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-common]'); // []
  document.querySelectorAll('[data-common*]'); // []
  // etc..
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure but `[data-common*]` could work?

Comment: It does not, I've tried that and it gives me an invalid selector error.

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199008/find-html-based-on-partial-attribute.  I think it is what you are looking for.

Comment: It is not. That is for writing a jQuery selector. I don't like or use jQuery unless it is **totally** necessary. I'm trying to write a selector not a filter function that that post is writing, these are similar but not the same problem/question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there are no selectors defined to partially match attribute names. What you're asking for doesn't exist.

For JavaScript you could filter a collection of elements using custom code (that is what jQuery does), but it will not work with `document.querySelectorAll`, nor can you define a custom selector for CSS, unless you're willing to suggest it on the w3c mailing list and deal with navigating the complex workflow that's involved in changing the CSS language.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. I just needed that clarification. If the technology for this arrives, I'll update the post.