# Find an element that has an attribute matching a pattern

Tags: javascript, dom

How to find all elements that have attributes that match pattern `data-foo-bar-*`, e.g.

```
<div data-foo-bar-id="" />
```

Using `document.querySelectorAll` with `foo-bar-*` pattern gives error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '[data-foo-bar-*]' is not a valid selector.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find HTML based on partial attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199008/find-html-based-on-partial-attribute)

Comment: @IvankaTodorova that question is entirely [tag:jquery] focused.

Comment: This is already answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16791596/4523369

Comment: @Keksike Looking for a partial attribute value (your link) is not the same as looking for a partial attribute name (the problem of this question)

Comment: There is no *attribute-name-starts-with*-selector-syntax, which you probably already know. Thus you need code to find those elements *by hand*. So the question is, what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: @Yoshi I was only half confident that there is no way using DOM API to match elements that have pattern matching attributes. The solution to this issue is to iterate through all (or a sub-set) of DOM nodes and match each attribute.

Comment: `*` is not a wildcard or regex. It means "includes" in DOM selector. And that's for values not the attribute name. `[data-foo-bar-*]` is incorrect syntax. `[data-foo-bar-*="some-value"]` is correct but will not give you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe iterating through all DOM elements and looking for this specific attribute might not be the best approach, but here's my try:

```
function querySelectorPattern(regex, element) {
  var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(element),
    found,
    regexp = new RegExp(regex);
  for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var attributes = elements[i].attributes;
    for (var k = 0; k < attributes.length; k++) {
      if(regexp.test(attributes[k].nodeName)) {
        console.log(elements[i]);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And a quick demo: https://jsfiddle.net/1rsngvy8/

Comment: This seems like an appropriate solution given the DOM API limitations.