# jQuery select data attributes with common keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I have two elements with the following setup:

```
<span data-placeholder-class="test-class"></span>
<span data-placeholder-template="/some/template.hbs"></span>
```

I'm using underscore to loop over any elements containing either of these attributes and then performing relevant actions if they do.

Currently this is done like so

```
_.each($('[data-placeholder-class], [data-placeholder-template]'), function cb(element) {
  // code goes here
})
```

Rather than have to define each data attribute to loop over I wondered if there was a way I could select all attributes that contain a common keyword, in this case placeholder. e.g.

```
_.each($('[data-placeholder-*]'), function cb(element) {
  // code goes here
})
```

Anyone know if this is possible at all?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery - How to select value by attribute name starts with](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26657398/jquery-how-to-select-value-by-attribute-name-starts-with)

Comment: Does that question have what you're looking for?

Comment: Not quite as they all require a common starting selector e.g. ".slide". Ideally I want to use the data attribute as the only selector so I don't have to add a custom class to any element that has these attributes and I can select by attributes instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find HTML based on partial attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199008/find-html-based-on-partial-attribute)

Comment: Right, but check out the info under the "EDIT" section of the selected answer. Above the "EDIT" is an answer specific to his question, but below it is a generic answer.

Comment: @woolm110 - Roberrrt's question find is actually better, since you're asking for keyword rather than startswith.

Answer (score 3):

You could consider using a separate function which creates your selector, so you won't have to type the selector in full (but you'll have to write the function of course).

e.q.:

```
function getSelector() {
    return Array.prototype.map.call(arguments, function(key) {
        return '[data-placeholder-' + key + ']';
    }).join(',');
}
```

This will return your desired selector, and works with 1...N arguments.

```
getSelector('class', 'template')
// returns "[data-placeholder-template],[data-placeholder-class]"

_.each($(getSelector('class', 'template')), function cb(element) {
    // code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate the `attributes` of a collection of elements, push the element to an array if the element `.attributes.name` matches a provided string variable

```js
var spans = document.querySelectorAll("span");

function filterAttrs(elems, attr, matches = []) {
  for (var elem of elems) {
    for (var attrs of elem.attributes) {
      // alternatively use `.indexOf()` or `RegExp()`
      // to match parts of string of `.name` or `.value`
      // of `.attributes` `NamedNodeMap`
      if (attrs.name.slice(0, attr.length) === attr) {
        matches.push({
          "element": elem,
          "attr": {
            "name": attrs.name,
            "value": attrs.value
          }
        })
      }
    }
  }
  return matches
}

var matches = filterAttrs(spans, "data-placeholder");

console.log(matches);

matches.forEach(function(match) {
  match.element.textContent = "matches:" + JSON.stringify(match.attr);
  match.element.style.color = "green";
});
```

```html
<span data-placeholder-class="test-class"></span>
<span data-placeholder-template="/some/template.hbs"></span>
<span data-not-placeholder-template="/some/template.hbs">
data-not-placeholder-template
</span>
<span data-not-placeholder-template="/some/template.hbs">
data-not-placeholder-template
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a jquery question, but there is a vanilla way of doing it, thanks to XPath queries :

The [`starts-with()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/starts-with) XPath function will do exactly that.

So the query `//*[@*[starts-with(name(), 'data-placeholder')]]` will give you what you are after.

unwrapped :

```
 '//' + // from root to anywhere in the tree
  '*' + // any kind of node
   '[@*' + // with any attribute
      '[starts-with(name(), "data-placeholder")]' + // which starts with "data-"
           ']'
```

```js
function getElementsByStartOfAttribute(start_of_attr) {
  var query = document.evaluate("//*[@*[starts-with(name(), '" + start_of_attr + "')]]",
    document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
  var elements = [];
  var el;
  while (el = query.iterateNext()) {
    elements.push(el);
  }
  return elements;
}

var placehodlers = getElementsByStartOfAttribute('data-placeholder');
console.log(placehodlers);
$(placehodlers).css('background', 'green');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span data-placeholder-class="test-class">should find me</span>
<span data-placeholder-template="/some/template.hbs">me too</span>
<span data-not-placeholder-template="/some/template.hbs">
data-not-placeholder-template
</span>
<span data-not-placeholder-template="/some/template.hbs">
data-not-placeholder-template
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var eles = $('span').filter(function() {
   for (var attrName in $(this).data()) {
     if (attrName.indexOf('placeholder') == 0) {
       return true;
     }
   }

   return false;
 });

 console.log(eles);
```

I hope this will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

SAMPLE HTML:

```
<span data-placeholder-class="test-class">test</span>
<span data-placeholder-template="/some/template.hbs">hahaha</span>
<span>hahahahaha</span>
<span data-test="/some/template.hbs">hahahahaha</span>
```

JS:

```
$('span').filter(function(ndx, item){
    var data = Object.keys($(item).data())[0]; // gets data name
    if (data === undefined) {
        return;
    }
    // checks if data starts with placeholder
    if (~(data.indexOf('placeholder'))) {
        // do anything to that item here
        return item;
    }
}).css('color', 'green');
```

Fiddle: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hn5ynffq/5/)

Hope this helps! :)