# How to check if the element is visible in my case?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a weird issue in my case.

I have something that is hidden but jquery can't find it.

html

```
<div id='test'>
    <h3>title here</h3>
</div>
```

css

```
#test h3 {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

js

```
if (('#test h3').is(':visible')) {
    alert('visible');
}
```

I am not supposed to get alert box because my h3 tag is hidden but the alert box keep popping up. Can anyone help me this weird issue? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your code is full of syntax errors. Please correct them.

Comment: @SethMcClaine - He's not being a dick, just pointing out the obvious.

Answer (score 5):

Since hiding the visibility still consumes space, jQuery considers them visible.

Here's a quote from [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/):

> Elements are considered visible if they consume space in the document. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with `visibility:hidden` or `opacity: 0` are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.

---

If you want to check if the element's `visibillity` is not set to `hidden`, use this:

```
if ( $('#test h3').css('visibility') == 'visible' ) {
    alert('visible');
}
```

---

To check for ancestors too, use this:

```
var visible = true;

$('#test h3').parents().addBack().each(function() {
    if ( $.css(this, 'visibility') != 'visible' ) return visible = false;
});

if ( visible ) {
    // do whatever...
}
```

---

You can abstract all that into a reusable [filter expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624345/getting-the-match-object-in-a-custom-filter-selector-in-jquery-1-8):

```
jQuery.expr[':']['visible-real'] = function(el) {

    var visible = true;

    $(el).parents().addBack().each(function () {
        if ( $.css(this, 'visibility') != 'visible' ) return visible = false;
    });

    return visible;
};
```

You can then use it whenever you need it as follows:

```
if ( $('#test h3').is(':visible-real') ) {
    alert('visible');
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3LGm7/